# Anyway to remove repetition for C# class properties?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, repeat

I have a class like this:

```cs
public class DbSettingsValues : Dictionary<string, string>
{

    public DbSettingsValues() { }

    public DbSettingsValues(Dictionary<string, string> values) : base(values) { }

    public string EmailApiServer
    {
        get => this.GetValueOrDefault(DbSettingsKeys.EmailApiServer, "");
        set => this[DbSettingsKeys.EmailApiServer] = value;
    }

    public string EmailApiKey
    {
        get => this.GetValueOrDefault(DbSettingsKeys.EmailApiKey, "");
        set => this[DbSettingsKeys.EmailApiKey] = value;
    }

    // about 15 more...

    // There is also a few difference, like this one:
    public int RegisterFirstEmailDelay
    {
        get => int.Parse(this.GetValueOrDefault(DbSettingsKeys.RegisterFirstEmailDelay, "24"));
        set => this[DbSettingsKeys.RegisterFirstEmailDelay] = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

So for every property I need to put the exact name 3 times. I understand this would be bad for maintenance later and prone to mistakes when I make more properties by copying (i.e. forget to replace the name in 1 of the 3 places).

Is there a better way to deal with this? Some solutions came to my mind:

- Something like the old T4, I don't see the T4 menu  anymore in VS2022, so I assume it doesn't work on .NET Core?
- Code Generator seem to require an external project. I assume this is how EF Core Scaffolding works? Can someone suggest a keyword/link to what I should look for? I.e. read a C# project, look for properties inside a class and generate a `.cs` file accordingly?

---

As of current specs, the key text is just the same:

```cs
    public const string EmailApiServer = nameof(EmailApiServer);
    public const string EmailApiKey = nameof(EmailApiKey);
    // ...
```

So technically I can just replace `DbSettingsKeys.EmailApiServer` to `nameof(EmailApiServer)` for example, but I am not sure it will stay the same later. Is it a good idea to proceed with this now and think about it later when specs change?

Update: I just realized that even with `nameof(PropertyName)`, it's still prone to copying issue since there is no error if I forget to change the name:

```cs
    // No error here because the name is valid
    public string EmailApiKey
    {
        get => this.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(EmailApiServer), "");
        set => this[nameof(EmailApiServer)] = value;
    }
```

I think something like `CallerMemberNameAttribute` maybe useful but I don't actually know how it works.

Comment: I dont think you can automate this on a code level but you can create snippets that will create these things for you automatically and error free. (does not resolve maintenance long term tho)

Comment: @DenisSchaf That's a great idea though to be honest last 5 times I tried using snippet I totally forgot I created them and just copy other code again (I know, great solution but my bad habit ). I have also heard about Code Generator but seem like it's not for Design Time and can't support IntelliSense. I am looking for a T4 alternative since I heard T4 doesn't work for .NET Core anymore (hopefully false)

Comment: A quick search finds people updating [T4 editor extensions for VS 2022](https://www.bricelam.net/2021/10/15/t4-language.html) so I don't think it's disappeared.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ah yes you are correct. The menu appears again once I added a `.tt` file! So it's a valid answer

Comment: Turned out T4 cannot really run on a .NET Core project due to not being able to locate assemblies (like System.Runtime.dll and the likes). Those files don't exist outside of .NET Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the keys really have the same names as the properties, you can indeed use `[CallerMemberName]` attributes to reduce the number of times that you have to type the property name.

For example:

```
public class DbSettingsValues : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public string EmailApiServer
    {
        get => getProperty();
        set => setProperty(value);
    }

    public string EmailApiKey
    {
        get => getProperty();
        set => setProperty(value);
    }

    public int RegisterFirstEmailDelay
    {
        get => getProperty(24);
        set => setProperty(value);
    }

    string getProperty(string defaultValue = "", [CallerMemberName] string? propName = default)
    {
        return this!.GetValueOrDefault(propName, defaultValue);
    }

    T getProperty<T>(T defaultValue, [CallerMemberName] string? propName = default)
    {
        var result = this!.GetValueOrDefault(propName, defaultValue!.ToString());
        return (T) Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T))!;
    }

    void setProperty(string value, [CallerMemberName] string? propName = default)
    {
        this[propName!] = value;
    }

    void setProperty<T>(T value, [CallerMemberName] string? propName = default)
    {
        this[propName!] = value!.ToString()!;
    }
}
```

It's not perfect, but it does reduce the chance of typos significantly.

Comment: Yes just tested this works for me for now :) I want to wait for a while in hope of a code generation solution as well. But if not, will mark this as answer in a few hours

Comment: Also I realized one danger if anyone has a design exactly like me: if you rename `EmailApiServer` **in `DbSettingsKeys`**, the property in `DbSettingsValues` won't be changed and you will have mismatch. But changing setting name is rare so it's better I suppose, just leave a comment in the `DbSettingsKeys` class to tell anyone renaming it to rename the property in `DbSettingsValues` as well.

Comment: To solve above problem, we simply ditch the `DbSettingsKeys` altogether and just use `nameof(DbSettingsValues.EmailApiServer)` for example.